# Cannot resolve symbol R and can't solve it

Tags: android

- I tried to solve this by trying solutions suggested in other questions but stil not able to get it. *
  In the console I'am getting this message

  Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
  Error:No resource identifier found for attribute 'roundIcon' in package 'android'
  Error:No resource identifier found for attribute 'roundIcon' in package 'android'
  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
  >   Information:BUILD FAILED
  >   Information:Total time: 6.496 secs
  >   Information:3 errors
  >   Information:0 warnings
  >   Information:See complete output in console

and my build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId smth
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

And for my MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

and for the manifest.xml

```
android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

Comment: I found it I have to remove the android:roundIcon

Comment: Connect your computer to the internet and try rebuilding your project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**roundIcon** is attributes in Android 8.0 (Oreo). If you want use **roundIcon** then so must change **minSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion** up to 25 in your app *build.gradle*. 
And if you want support *old version* whose will need remove *android:roundIcon* and use android:icon for old version.
[fix roundIcon in android 8.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDx5b.png)

Answer (score 0):

as you are using  **android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"** inside your manifest file, so to make it work you need to update your  **minSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion**  to API 25 atleast inside your 
 **build.gradle** file